# How to define a 28-bit integer in Ghidra

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, type-reconstruction

I'm working on reverse-engineering firmware for an STM32G0B1, which has two onboard CAN modules, in Ghidra.

I think that a proper data structure for both the Tx and Rx FIFO buffers would help me greatly, and also I'm trying to learn more about Ghidra in the process.

The node ID is either an 11- or 28-bit unsigned integer (though I'll be treating every ID as a 28-bit integer), and I'm struggling to define that number as a data type.

I haven't found anything in either Google search or ChatGPT either.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but my best guess that defining a struct with a 28 bits long bitfield is the way to correctly model this.